# How do I retrieve or setup a password in CVS pserver?

Tags: password, cvs

I currently using a CVS pserver for code management here at work. However, I forgot what my password was. Is there a way I can reset my password? I am pretty sure the password is encrypted in some manner (perhaps MD5?).

I did do a search for similar questions, but was not able to find any. If this is a duplicate, please let me know and I will take it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the password; it's encrypted one-way.  You can set a new one, however.

The usual way to manage this is to have a checkout of the CVSROOT module, edit the passwd file and `cvs commit` it.

If nobody has working access to a checkout of CVSROOT, you can always go into the CVSROOT directory inside the CVS repository and edit passwd directly.  Matt Simmons's suggestion for generating a properly encrypted password will work for that.

Answer (score 2):

I've always used 'htpasswd' to generate mine.

```
 htpasswd -nb username password
```

Paste the hash into the proper field.